# How to KEEP only Duplicated data in Libre Office Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How can I keep only duplicated data and delete all single data in Libre Office Calc? I have nearly 90,000 rows and only one column (A).

Answer (score 1):

- In B1, enter the formula `=COUNTIF(A$1:A$90000,A1)`
- Copy cell B1
- In the name box (to the left of the formula bar) type `B2:B90000` and press Enter.  This range should become selected (highlighted).  Paste.  Now column B indicates how many copies of each line are present in the list.
- Select (highlight) the entire list + counts by typing in the name box `A1:B90000` and pressing Enter
- Go to Data → Filter → Standard Filter
- Select Field Name `Column B`, Condition `>`, and Value `1`.  Press OK.
- Now your original data is filtered.  To get an unfiltered copy without the singles, select `A1:A90000`, copy it, and paste it to a new sheet.